# My batch script has an unexepcted value

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

My for loop is shown below:

```
for %%j in %JARLIST% do call wget %%j
```

When running this for loop I get the following exception

[image: Error From Terminal]

I am creating the array as follows :

```
set JARLIST="%BASEURL%/MessageBundle_ar.jar"
set JARLIST=%JARLIST% "%BASEURL%/MessageBundle_en.jar"
```

Have I missed something that the exception is being thrown?

Comment: This is all being run inside a batch file

Comment: The second line of the help file for the `FOR` command is this: `FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]`. **Reading is Fun!**

Comment: Rookie mistake, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%j in (%JARLIST%) do...
```

should fix the problem. The list must be in parentheses.